# Lisp list in java

Tags: java

I have made an attempt at writing this code but it doesn't seem to do much, am kind of new to the concept of lisp lists therefore i don't quiet understand what i should be doing, anyways here is what i have tried:

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class removNum{
      public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a list (of integers): ");
        String str = in.nextLine();
        LispList<Integer> list = parseIntLispList(str);
        System.out.println("The list you entered is:");
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println("Enter an integer:");
        list = removePos(list);
        System.out.println(list); 
     }
     public static LispList<Integer> parseIntLispList(String str){
       String line = str.trim();
       String contents = line.substring(1,line.length()-1).trim();
       if(contents.length()==0)
          return LispList.empty();
       String[] nums = contents.split(",");
       LispList<Integer> list = LispList.empty();
       for(int i=nums.length-1; i>=0; i--){
          String num = nums[i].trim();
          list = list.cons(Integer.parseInt(num));
       }
       return list;
     }
     public static LispList removePos(LispList list, int n){
        if(0==n){
         return list.getTail();
        }
       else{
         return new LispList(list.getHead(),removePos(list.getTail(),n-1));
       }
     }
  }
```

Well basically what i'm trying to do is to write a recursive method which takes a list and an integer x, and deletes the integer at position x in the list, e.g. if the list is [2,5,6,40,8,9,45] and the integer is 2, the method should return [2,5,40,8,9,45] so integer at the position 2 is removed from the list.

I don't expect anyone to write up the solution for me but a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example does not match your description of what you are trying to do. "Deletes the integer at position x", but there is no integer at the 40th position - 40 is at the 4th position - and in your example you get rid of the rest of the list as well as deleting the integer. Which is right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it doesn't do much".  What is it actually doing wrong?  It's hard to tell, because I'm not familiar with this `LispList` class that you're using.  Maybe you can post the JavaDoc for the `cons` method here, as this is the part that I think you might have got wrong.

Comment: @David Wallace What i mean by it doesn't do much is that i can't seem to run it, it give me an error "method removePos in class removNum cannot be applied to given types;" and it highlights the line "list = removePos(list);" in my code.

Comment: @moonshadow sorry, what i mean to say is that it should only remove the interger at that position and nothing else in the list.

Comment: That's because the method `removePos` that you've written has two parameters.  But in the line that the compiler highlights, you've only passed it one argument.

Comment: @David Wallace even when i pass both arguments i still get the same error

Comment: What are the two arguments you're passing?  If they're a `LispList` and an `int`, you shouldn't be getting this error.

Comment: @David Wallace I pass both `list,n`

Comment: And what is `n`?  It's not in your listing.

Comment: `n` is the integer used in the `removePos` method, sorry for the complete hasell but could you please write down what you mean

Comment: I asked what value you are passing as the second argument, when you call `removePos` from within `main`.  You said you were passing `list` and `n`.  I asked what `n` is, in the context of `main`.  So I want to know what the second argument you are passing to `removePos` is.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very similar question answered at http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/317223-delete-elements-in-the-list-using-lisplist/

I don't know whether the `LispList` class you're using implements the `java.util.List` interface, but if it does, you might look into the `indexOf` and `subList` methods, described at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html.